# How to filter a dataset based on keys from another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've a dataset of book ratings which looks like:

```
ratings.head()

    User-ID     ISBN    Book-Rating
0   276725  034545104X  0
1   276726  0155061224  5
2   276727  0446520802  0
3   276729  052165615X  3
4   276729  0521795028  6
```

and I want to filter the dataset by users who liked particular book.

I've tried:

```
lotr_ratings = ratings[ratings['ISBN'] == '0345339703'] 
liked_lotr = lotr_ratings[lotr_rating['Book-Rating'] == 10] #readers who like lotr
liked_lotr = liked_lotr['User-ID'].to_frame() 
ratings[ratings['User-ID'] == liked_lotr] # Filter the original dataset
```

Failed for:

> MemoryError

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When comparing using `==` you'll be broadcasting your `df` to do (potentially) thousands of comparions, and memory will explode. Instead, use `isin` to find whihc values in `liked_lots['User-ID']` are also in `ratins['User-ID']`

Comment: Does `ratings[(ratings['ISBN']=='0345339703') & (ratings['Book-Rating'] == 10)]` return what you expect? Less intermediary steps need less memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to create a new dataframe based on multiple conditions. Do it like this:

```
conditions = (ratings['ISBN'] == '0345339703') & (ratings['Book-Rating'] == 10)

like_lotr = ratings[conditions]
```

Comment: Yeah, but that gives me only a df with one particular book. The issue is one user might rate more than 1 book. I want to find what other books the particular group (who liked book isbn 0345339703) likes.

Comment: OK, so maybe just filter by the rating=10 and then pd.merge the original list back to the df with just 10 ratings on the user-id